# jQuery Validate complex page with lots of forms, and especially elements not in a form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate

I want to validate a pages inputs that are not in a form. I know that `jquery.validate` has a hard dependency on the inputs being inside a form but I have a single page APP written in MVC with a lot of AJAX partials, lots of selects and inputs that update various other inputs dynamically.

```
<div id="form">
    <!-- lots of other fieldgroups with code like this -->
   <div class="fieldGroup">
      <label>Manufacturer</label>
      <form action="/quotes/?orgname=OptionsLtd&amp;accountid=%7BD174E073-685E-E311-84AE-12D0D8A96A66%7D" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#ModelsList" data-ajax-url="/Partials/ModelsSelect" id="form1" method="post">                    <input type="hidden" name="actuality" class="selected-actuality-value" value="1">
       <input type="hidden" name="vehicleType" class="selected-vehicletype-value" value="1">

      </form>
   </div>

<!-- Other selects and inputs outside partial forms that are required, but do not submit any ajax on change -->
 <select id="importantAndRequired" required="required"><options></select>

<!-- some more AJAX forms -->

</div>
```

Then I have a save button. Not a submit, just a button bound to jquery click.
I create a very complex JSON object based on the input names I require, that creates a "ViewModel" which represents a C# Class with the entire complex Classes, Lists and arrays. I submit the JSON to MVC WebAPI, the API parses the JSON as expected and all my values are processed on the server.

So, how on earth can I validate inputs, which are required to be selected, like drop downs, checkboxes, before I build my JSON Object?

*jQuery validate expects all the inputs be inside a form, but cannot change my `<div id="form"` to `<form id=form` because the entire `div` contains many AJAX forms using `<form>` , and mostly inputs that do not require validation which are in the AJAX forms, just other inputs scattered around the page.*

Answer (score 0):

Found, and used the build in JavaScript validity. Check on all the inputs that I am building my JSON object from, and put a validation message next to each input, which gets displayed if not met. Sure, not as customisable as jQuery validation but that is not a requirement. Besides, adding custom validation would be easy enough anyway.

```
function validate(inputs){
    $('.validationMessage').hide();

    var allValid = true;
    $(inputs).each(function (idx, el) {
        if (!el.validity.valid) {
            allValid = false;
            $(el).next('.validationMessage').show();
        }
    });

    return allValid;
}
```